# How to serialize an array of objects to a JSON JValue?

Tags: arrays, json, scala, lift

Having an array of objects I'd like to serialize them into JSON (a JValue instance).
I've tried the folowing 2 variants of combining JSON entities:

```
def items : Array[FooBar] = Array (new FooBar(1), new FooBar(2), new FooBar(3))
def toJson : JValue = {
  val jItems : Array[JValue]= items.map(i => i.toJson)

  // variant 1.
  // val jItemsC = jItems.reduceLeft[JValue](_~_)

  // variant 2.
  val jItemsC = jItems.reduceLeft((a : JObject, b : JValue) => a ~ b)

  "items" -> jItemsC
}
```

The first (and the second with (a : JValue, b : JValue)) says
`value ~ is not a member of net.liftweb.json.package.JValue`

The second says
`overloaded method value ~ with alternatives:
(right: net.liftweb.json.package.JObject)net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject <and>

(right: (String, net.liftweb.json.package.JValue))net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JObject

 cannot be applied to (net.liftweb.json.package.JValue)`

So how what's the problem and how can my problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

These should work:

```
val a = Array("a", "b", "c")
Extraction.decompose(a)
```

or

```
JArray(a.toList map JString.apply)
```

Comment: `Extraction.decompose(a)` (where a is an Array of instances of a class of mine) causes `could not find implicit value for parameter formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats` compilation error.

Comment: `JArray(a.toList map JString.apply)` causes `type mismatch; found : String => net.liftweb.json.JsonAST.JString; required: code.model.Item => ?` compilation error.

Comment: `JArray(a.toList)` seems to work (compiles at least) when a is an array of JValue objects.